# Are RIFTS Psi-Hounds fertile?

Tags: lore, rifts

A few years back the magazine the *Rifter* published some material I submitted to Palladium- a small town in the *Rifts* setting, whose population partly consisted of Psi-Hound deserters and their offspring. I'm embarrassed to say it took some time later for something to occur to me- if Psi-hounds were created in Coalition labs, would the CS even *want* them to be able to reproduce on their own? Or would they be more likely to sterilize them upon their 'births'?

Comment: How do you expect to get a definitive answer to this? It's *your* material, and they published it. Seems perfectly *possible* if you insert your own rationale for why *or* why not. What would an authoritative answer even look like here?

Comment: @ShadowRanger- maybe they originally planned for psi-hounds to be sterile and forgot about it or overlooked it- stranger things have happened.

Comment: But they were always humping my leg ...  Darned psi dogs

Comment: @kingofpanes: So you're asking us to figure out what is inside the head of every person who has worked on Rifts to confirm they didn't make a mistake when they chose to publish your material? I feel like the choice to publish your material makes it more canon than anything going on inside their heads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The CS doesn't spay or neuter Dog Boys

***Rifts Ultimate Edition*** (June 2010) begins its **Dog Boy O.C.C.** with the following description: "All Dog Boys have their origins with the CS [Coalition States], although an increasing number… are 'free born'…, the natural born offspring of lab created Dog Boys who have gone AWOL frm the Coalition Army" (142).

So that's that, although further details are omitted. (There are no [Punnett squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punnett_square), for example.) So while the game does take a few pages to detail the lives of CS Dog Boys—they're treated like dumb, disposable servants—, so far as I can tell, the game doesn't explain *why* the CS does *not* sterilize them. I'm not really in a position to speculate on the genetic decisions of a fascist post-apocalyptic empire, but [***Rifts Lone Star***](http://palladium-store.com/1001/product/825-Rifts-World-Book-13-Lone-Star.html) (2001) might go into more detail about this subject.

Comment: And all this time I thought I was being original- XD...

Comment: @kingofpanes I didn't check the original *Rifts*, so maybe you were, and it became canon after you wrote it?

Comment: I wouldn't bet on it- what I wrote I wrote about 4-5 years after what you posted.